# cloned a github repo, created a new branch -> can I push?

Tags: git, github

So I cloned a repo on github locally.
I didn't have any rights on that repo yet.
Then I created a new branch locally.

I'd like to push my new branch to github,
I now also should be listed as collaborator.

Can I do this?
How do I do it?
I am used to command line git and this project
is running inside eclipse (android project).

Thanks

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo https://help.github.com/categories/63/articles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not good idea, really.

Usual workflow looks like this

1. You should `fork` repo to your account in github web-interface.
2. `clone` you fork to local machine.
3. Make new `branch` (call it by feature you want to implement or fixes you want to do).
4. Change code, `commit` it and `push` new branch to your fork.
5. Create `pull request` to original repo.

Something like this.

EDIT: links by @zerkms in first comment are very useful. I think it will be more informative to read them, than my answer.

Comment: Actually your answer is a good and short roadmap, for those who are too lazy to read articles :-)

Comment: I understand. However, why is it not a good idea if the repo owner wants to collaborate with me, as I met him personally?

Comment: Repo owner can add you to collaborators if he doesn't want to review your code before pulling it in. He can do it on collaborators page on github https://github.com/repoowner/reponame/admin/collaboration